# regex for group condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using below pattern

```
^(?:0067|0)[0-9\\s.\\/-]{6,20}$
```

I want to validate numbers starting with zero or with double zero following few numbers. Example

01796568801  - should be valid,
0089737732 - should be invalid,
0067214356 - should be valid

But my pattern is making all valid. Please advise how can I make it to take only single 0 or 0067?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz63rgs2/

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is making all valid because you are specifying that. The part `[0-9\\s.\\/-]{6,20}` is allowin whatever number from 6 to 20 chars long.

For instance, you could change your regex to this:

```
^(?:0067|0)[1-9][0-9\s.\/-]{5,19}$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vTUSWR/1)**

Answer (score 0):

To figure out, whats going wrong, it is best to understand what you are requesting:

```
 /^(?:0067|0)[0-9\\s.\\/-]{6,20}$/
```

says:

`0067` or `0`, followed by `0-9` or `blank` or `/` or `-` for 6-20 times

So, all your examples "match" this condition:

```
   01796568801   => 0 1796568801
   0089737732301 => 0 089737732301
   0067214356    => 0067 214356
or 0067214356    => 0 067214356
```

https://regex101.com/r/EpZumK/1

To give you a general solution, more input is required, because here your options `0067` and `0` are nothing more than `start with 0`, cause any case, where 0067 is not 100% matched, the `start with 0` condition will match as well, if string length is not exceeded.

Edit: Federico Piazzas solution will work in the case outlined, but such a "case-dependenant" solution seems bad to me, because software always "grows" - and in 3 months, 0049 might be valid as well, requiring code-maintenance...

Why don't you use two input-elements: One for the country code (or 0 if local) and one for the number?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure if javascript supports negative lookahead but if it does you can try the below pattern:

```
^(0067|0(?!0))(\d){6,19}\s+-$
```

Match: 01796568801 - | 0067214356 -

No match: 0089737732 - | 0008973773 -

I wasn't sure about the white space after the remaining numbers before the dash so I made it 1 or more white space characters are required.